# Remove the selected item in a ListView from a SQL database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, listview

Im trying to create a method that removes my selected item(from a listview)  from the database table `mrydenEntities()`
Database is setup with `EntityFramework` and Database First model.

Im getting this error

> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements

Which I am pretty certain means that my code `recipeToRemove = context.Recipe.First(r => r.Id.Equals(Id));` is not getting any equals match.

I am not sure what Im doing wrong, and Im running out on options how to move forward.

My Db class:

```
public class Dbconnection : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

        public string RecipeName { get; set; }
        public string RecipeIngredients { get; set; }
        public string CookingTime { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }

        mrydendbEntities context = new mrydendbEntities();
        public Recipe recipeToRemove;
        public Recipe Table { get; set; }         

        public void DbconnectionRemove(string RecipeName, string Ingredients, string CookingTime, int Id)
        {
            recipeToRemove = context.Recipe.First(r => r.Id.Equals(Id)); //This is giving me an error System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements
            context.Recipe.Remove(recipeToRemove);
            context.SaveChanges();
            MessageBox.Show(recipeToRemove.RecipeName);
        }
    }
```

My Code Behind:

```
public partial class ViewAll : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string RecipeName { get; set; }

        public string Ingredients { get; set; }

        public string CookingTime { get; set; }

        private Recipe _recipe;
        public Recipe Recipe
        {
            get { return _recipe; }
            set
            {
                if(_recipe != value)
                {
                    _recipe = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Recipe");
                }
            }
        }

        public ViewAll()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadItemTemplate();
        }

        public void LoadItemTemplate()
        {
            mrydendbEntities dbe = new mrydendbEntities();
            listOfRecipes.ItemsSource = dbe.Recipe.ToList();
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //My button event to remove the selected table row.
        {
            var remove = new Dbconnection();
            remove.DbconnectionRemove(RecipeName, Ingredients, CookingTime, Id);
        }
```

My mrydendbEntities class:

```
using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class mrydendbEntities : DbContext
    {
        public mrydendbEntities()
            : base("name=mrydendbEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Recipe> Recipe { get; set; }
    }
```

EDIT: Changed `recipeToRemove = context.Recipe.First(r => r.Id.Equals(Id));` to be replaced with `recipeToRemove = context.Recipe.FirstOrDefault(r => r.RecipeName.Equals(RecipeName));` which gave me a new error message at the row `context.Recipe.Remove(recipeToRemove);`

> System.ArgumentNullException "Value cannot be null"

Comment: Where and when do you set the `Id`? Because right now its always 0.

Comment: Can you please update your post with relevant tags?

Comment: What's `mrydendbEntities`? Context doesn't seem to be getting used anywhere but that method.

Comment: @Haytam I changed to use recipeToRemove = context.Recipe.FirstOrDefault(r => r.RecipeName.Equals(RecipeName)) instead of r.Id

Comment: @Hayden It's the class created by EntityFramework. It's actually being used in another function where I add data to the database. I chose to exclude it from my post. Sorry if that was confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

I had to change 
`recipeToRemove = context.Recipe.FirstOrDefault(r => r.RecipeName.Equals(RecipeName))`
to 
`recipeToRemove = context.Recipe.First(r => r.RecipeName.Equals(r.RecipeName));`

Comment: you weren't using recipe name before, you were using `id`. I don't know what rules you have in your database, but you generally don't want to select items by name, because you might have 2 records with the same name. You should do it by `id`, the way you were

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right. I will need to improve that later on. But for now Im just trying to learn how to get my code to actually work. :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
recipeToRemove = context.Recipe.First(r => r.Id.Equals(Id)); //This is giving me an error System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements
```

do this:

```
recipeToRemove = context.Recipe.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id.Equals(Id));
```

And then check the results for `<null>` before proceeding.

`First` will error if there are no results, but `FirstOrDefault` will return `<null>` if there are no results.

Comment: I'm getting System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.

Comment: A I mentioned, you have to check for null before procedding. If `recipeToRemove` is null, you have to handle that